# Separate grounding for analog and digital portions of circuitry

Tags: analog, grounding

A datasheet suggests separate grounding for analog and digital portions of circuitry (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am26c32.pdf#page=12).

Is this to say that the IC's outputs should have a separate ground to the IC's power supply (VDD)?

If so, how is this possible when all components operate from the same supply?

Comment: It is "good PCB layout practices." Also, this question seems to be a duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/128637/how-should-i-connect-agnd-and-dgnd
(See the comments for even more duplicates.)

Comment: It *used to be* good practice. This is a slow device and separate planes probably would be ok. The device itself is ancient (1990). I answered this for someone using modern (fast) logic. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/185306/analog-power-ground-planes-doubts/185320#185320

Comment: I thought 52Mbps was quite fast? So all inputs/output on the IC can share the same ground, and I shouldn't run into problems?

Comment: @B4039 The output transition time is listed as 4 ns typical, which is about 24 inches on most flavours of FR-4. Provided the grounds do not have more than about 2 inches of loop, there should be little effect.

Comment: Would having the digital signal reach ground first make any difference?

Comment: I suppose as the PCB I'm using only has 1 ground plane, I have no choice but to share it between digital and ground. Is the idea that a PCB may have 2 ground layers, which you can use to separate analog (I assume in this case it means the power supply?) and digital? Can one power supply have two separate ground planes?

Comment: @B4039 - if you take a look at the previous answer I referenced, you can get an idea of how to do this with a single plane.

Comment: Don't split the ground plane. This is a frequently asked question. I used to answer every time, but I got tired of it. You SHOULD be aware of what ground currents do, and make sure that potentially noisy signals stay away from sensitive analog inputs. Also, be aware of large DC currents which could introduce a small DC offset at the input of a high gain amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this to say that the IC's outputs should have a separate ground to
>   the IC's power supply (VDD)? If so, how is this possible when all components operate from the same supply?

I suppose your referring to this:

> Separate grounding for analog and digital portions of circuitry is one
>   of the simplest and most-effective methods of noise suppression. One
>   or more layers on multilayer PCBs are usually devoted to ground
>   planes. A ground plane helps distribute heat and reduces EMI noise
>   pickup. Make sure to physically separate digital and analog grounds,
>   paying attention to the flow of the ground current.

The current will return back to the source (usually the ground pin of the cable tied to the power supply ground). In the DC world this usually means the shortest path (assuming resistance of the ground plane is equal and the plane is continuous). In the AC world this means the lowest impedance path, which usually means the return current will follow the trace that is carrying the AC signal because of mutual inductance.

Regardless, if a return current crosses through an analog subsection, it will show up as a (usually small) voltage. This voltage offset will cause noise in an analog subsection.

The best thing (in my experience) is to find where the return current is going and orient the analog subsection so currents do not cross through it. This allows you to maintain a simple grounding system, with a continuous ground plane.

Another way to do it is with slots in the board:

[image]

Source: [Staying well grounded](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/staying-well-grounded.html)

A problem with slots is they turn the PCB into a dipole antenna, and if the design needs to be FCC compliant, it may fail.

Another way is to isolate the grounds with digital isolation, and or a star ground. Both of which I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: The other idea would be to place the precision analog circuitry (if possible) somewhere else, rather than in between the main power input and the load.

Comment: Thats option 1) Quote: "The best thing (in my experience) is to find where the return current is going and orient the analog subsection so currents do not cross through it"

Answer (score 1):

> Is this to say that the IC's outputs should have a separate ground to the IC's power supply (VDD)?

Ground separation does not mean to "have a separate ground to the IC's power supply". The method is a good PCB layout techniques and involves separation of AGND and PGND on the board into two separate ground planes **connected to each other at one point**. Where AGND is signal ground and PGND is the ground connection over which higher pulsed currents flow.

These connections can be: **single point** (series or parallel), **multi point** (for high frequency or low frequency signals),etc . These ground connections are selected based on frequency and noise.
The datasheet suggests you to use an approach like in this picture:
[image]

Also, the separation should be maintained across whole PCB and to not cross sensitive analog section with noisy digital ground.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Separating analog and digital ground planes is good practice and helps reduce noise. Its not true that all components must operate from the same supply. Infact, you can have separate power supplies for the digital and analog circuitry. They may be supplied from the same source originally, but filtered as not to interfere with each other.

Here is an example of this: https://m.eet.com/media/1049897/C0130-Figure3.gif

Comment: Separate planes can *induce* noise due to ground loops; it all depends on edge rates.

Comment: I don’t think the OP was stating that they MUST operate from the same supply. I think the question was asking about how to handle it when they do operate from the same supply.

Comment: EMI consultants like it when people split ground planes. When the boards fail emissions testing, it is more business for them!