# Advice on generating a negative supply rail (-5V) in an embedded, mixed signal design

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, instrumentation-amplifier, negative-voltage

I'm designing a board that can take an input DC supply of between +8 and +36V DC (+12V nominally) and needs rails of +5V, +3.3V, +2.5V and +1.8V. My current design uses a step-down regulator (LMR23625) to generate the +5V and I use LDOs to generate the rest. This all works fine. This block diagram illustrates it:

[image: original design]

The problem is that I also have an analog section to the board (8x INA141 instrumentation amplifiers and an 8 channel ADC). The INA141s need a negative supply rail of -5V. What is the best way for me to generate the -5V? I was thinking about daisy-chaining the TPS63700 off the LMR23635, e.g.: 
[image: TPS63700 daisy-chain]

Is this a good idea or should I consider something like a dual-supply/split-rail regulator in place of the LMR23625?

I'm not constrained for PCB space. The board is 200x60 mm (4 layer, double sided) and I can dedicate a good 3rd of that to power supplies. The overall system current is maximum 2.5A (nominally lower).

The worst case current requirement of the -5V rail 80 mA, maybe 100 mA to be safe (10mA per INA141 x 8 + some head-room). Nominal value is about 3 mA each.

Comment: Sorry, this is just where engineering gets tedious. You need to find all the possible solutions that meet your needs, then figure out which one is lowest cost (or optimizes some other secondary "want" specification). There's no way for anybody else to answer without intimate knowledge of your design and its requirements.

Comment: You have considered whether a single-supply op-amp could work instead, right?

Comment: @Justin Yes, unfortunately I have no choice with the op-amps. I'm stuck having to use the dual-supply op-amps.

Comment: @The Photon This may well be the case. I decided to create the question just on the off-chance that someone has done something similar and could share any lessons they learnt.

Comment: The problem is that you asked for the **best** way, but you haven't told us about the important constraints for your design. How much current do you need? How much area do you have?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Ok, I've edited the question to provide more detail. Perhaps the term 'best' is too strong so I've changed the title to ask for advice instead.

Comment: How much current do you need *on the -5V rail*? This is a very easy problem to solve if you don't need much current, more difficult if you need a lot.

Comment: @Hearth Good question - I've updated the question with this. I think 100 mA would be safe. I realize that is a lot though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the inverting switcher is a reasonable idea. However I would suggest a couple of things to improve the analog front the performance.

1. Have the main converter LMR23625 produce 6V instead.
2. Use an LDO to produce the 5V for your analog.
3. Have the TPS63700 invert the 6V to -6V instead.
4. Use a negative LDO to produce the -5V for your analog.

This will give you the quietest voltage rails for analog as long as you work to isolate the GND regions properly for analog as well.

Comment: +1, although I personally fall into the "one continuous ground plane - do not split the GND plane" camp. See ["Why exactly is it discouraged to gap the ground plane?"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329608/why-exactly-is-it-discouraged-to-gap-the-ground-plane) .